# Is it possible for a python socket server to be created automatically over the same network without the client having to input the host's IP

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, host

I'm creating a socket connection for a game which is multiplayer, where the 2 users can play together on different computers connected to the same internet.

So at the moment my host starts off as something like this:

## Host

```
import socket  
HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
print ("connecting... ({})".format(HOST)) #prints the IP address for the client
PORT = 56258
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)
c, addr = s.accept()
```

And my client is something like where i manually have to enter the IP address:

## Client

```
import socket
HOST = "xx.xxx.xx.xx"   # Here I manually enter the IP address before running the program which I found from the output of the host program

PORT = 56258       # The same port as used by the host
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)   
print ("connecting to",HOST)
s.connect((HOST,PORT))
print ('done')
```

Is there a way where I can make the two applications in such a way I don't need to keep entering the IP address for the client and still connect in the same way.

Furthermore if possible, is there anyway I can make the program one program for both the host and client so it scans to see if a connection is made on that port, if so create a server and vice versa for connecting to one.

Thank You

Comment: In the client, you could iterate all your *LAN* *IP*s, and for each try to connect on specified port. If connection succeeds, then that's your server (besides that you should design some simple handshake protocol - send smth and get smth else back - in order for both ends to check that the remote peer is who they expect it to be). Also since this could take a long time, if an event is generated (e.g. a key press) interrupt it. Regarding the 2nd question, a connection can't exist before the server.

Answer (score 0):

It is a rather common use case, when a client does not know in advance the address of a server in a **Local**<sup>1</sup> Area Network - think of DHPC, or finding a *master browser* in a peer to peer network. It is usually solved by first sending an UDP request to the broadcast address, and the reply of the server includes its own address.

That means that the server side actually contains 2 servers: the normal server that *does the job*, and an UDP server that only waits for broadcast request and answers them by giving its own address. Simply you have to decide the format of the request and response and the port that they use.

---

<sup>1</sup> broadcasts packets are not resent by routers, so they are limited to a LAN